# how do I correctly negate zsh globbing expressions?

Tags: zsh, globbing

I want to list all files but those ending with owp: Hence I tried:

```
  ls -l *.(^owp)
  zsh: unknown sort specifier
  ls -l *(^owp) 
  zsh: unknown sort specifier
  ls -l *[^o][^w][^p] # does not work either, missing some files
```

none worked. How do I that in a correct manner? My .zshrc has "set extendedglob".

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try either:

```
ls -l ^*.owp
```

(i.e. match anything except the pattern `*.owp`)

or:

```
ls -l *~*.owp
```

(i.e. match anything that matches the pattern `*` but does not match `*.owp`)

See `man zshexpn` => `FILENAME GENERATION` => `Glob Operators` for more on this.

---

Appended `()` in glob patterns are for glob qualifiers, whereas you want a glob operator.

What `*.(^owp)` does is:

1. Match all file names ending with a dot
2. if they aren't pipes `(^p)`, and
3. sort the matches `(o)` by "`w`" => "unknown sort specifier"

See `man zshexpn` => `FILENAME GENERATION` => `Glob Qualifiers` for more on this.

Comment: ^*.owp did the job. whooa, for what *.(^owp) really does :)

Comment: For anyone who can't get this to work, you need to set the `extendedglob` option in Zsh.

Comment: @DBedrenko: thanks! N.B.: done via `setopt extendedglob`

Comment: I found [this](https://www.refining-linux.org/archives/37-ZSH-Gem-2-Extended-globbing-and-expansion.html) useful as a quick summary for anyone interested in glob qualifiers.

Answer (score -1):

I was having this same issue trying to pull a branch down from git.

Example:`feature/this_feature(error_1)`

I had to escape the parenthesis: `feature/this_feature\(error_1\)`